# Count lines of query result

Tags: sql

Would like to count records in the result of aggregate query. So if my original data looks like this:

```
========================
Field 1 Field 2 Field 3
------------------------
aaa ccc 10
aaa ccc 10
aaa ddd 10
aaa ddd 10
bbb ddd 10
bbb ddd 10
bbb eee 10
```

I group by Field 1, Field 2  and I do Sum of Field 3
So result looks:

```
========================
Field 1 Field 2 Field 3
------------------------
aaa ccc 20
aaa ddd 20
bbb ddd 20
ddd eee 10
```

I would like to count, how many times each value appears in Field 1 and Field 2.

So that result would look like this:

```
======================================================
Field 1 Field 2 Field 3 Count Field 1   Count Field 2
------------------------------------------------------
aaa ccc 20  2   1
aaa ddd 20  2   2
bbb ddd 20  2   2
ddd eee 10  2   1
```

I tried to use Cound function, but it counts original table, so shows result of original table, I get result:

```
======================================================
Field 1 Field 2 Field 3 Count Field 1   Count Field 2
------------------------------------------------------
aaa ccc 20  4   2
aaa ddd 20  4   4
bbb ddd 20  3   4
ddd eee 10  3   1
```

Comment: Would you care to share your SQL statement with us?

Comment: What platform do you need it for? MySQL, MSSQL, Oracle or something else.

Answer (score 0):

Most databases support window/analytic functions.  These can be combined in aggregations to do what you want:

```
select field1, field2, sum(field3) as sumfield3,
       count(*) over (partition by field1) as numField1,
       count(*) over (partition by field2) as numField2
from table t
group by tield1, field2;
```